# Can anyone explain how to execute a visual studio program?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-code, coding-style

I’m new to programming and in high school. I’ve been in an IT program for a few months. This question is asked a lot on Stack Exchange, but I hope I can get an answer that’s a little more clear...

I’m currently working with C# and C++. How would you publish VS programs in these formats?

*thank you so much!*

edit: sorry for the vague question from before. I’m just beginning to learn for myself, and I wasn’t sure how describe it.

Comment: What do you mean by "publish"?

Comment: `project properties` > `publish` > `publish now` ?

Comment: Do you mean generate a executable from the source code?

Comment: @MattJones Sorry for not being clear enough... I meant as in how to make a program be able to run without running it on VS.

Comment: @user9601822 Right click project > open in folder explorer > bin > debug/release. That's were your exe is, you can run it from there no vs needed (you can also move it but move the other files (dll's) in the folder too, those are needed)

Comment: Not sure why this is getting so many downvotes... I know the whole 'publish' mess had me stumped for a while when I started.

Comment: @Nyerguds Thank you for understanding. Being a newbie is hard...

Comment: @MrVoid Yes... sorry for being vague...

Comment: Dont worry, this is plenty of gurus but also of salty people, keep going!

Comment: It's getting downvotes because it's something that could very easily be googled.

Comment: @TJWolschon If was a user with at least 1K of points, I will down vote it, but is a noob and at least comment that can be easily googled with the right keywords, is about contribution not about perfection

Comment: I did try to google this first. First match on google is a video that advises taking stuff from the obj folder, and the official MSDN fails to mention the target folder or the .vshost debug stuff. So yes, this warranted a real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your Visual Studio, you should see the build configurations dropdown. Set that to "Release".

[image: Build config]

Go to the properties of your project. Note, project, not solution. If you have multiple, this should be the one set as startup project. In the properties, go to the "Build" tab. Scroll down a little and you will see the "Output path", generally under "bin\". This is a subfolder of your project folder, and it is where you can find your final built files.

Now, once you got your build config set to Release, rebuild the solution (in the menus, it's "Build" -> "Rebuild Solution"), and then go to that folder. You will see all the built project files in there.

Note that there may be a number of files there that have the name of your project but with `.vshost` behind your project name. Typical names are `ProjectName.vshost.application`, `ProjectName.vshost.exe`, `ProjectName.vshost.config`, `ProjectName.vshost.manifest`. Ignore all those; they are for Visual Studio debugging. All the other files in there should be your full program bundle.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Note, the difference between `Debug` and `Release` is internal optimising. In `Debug` mode every single operation is executed exactly as it is written in code, while in `Release`, unused data that appears in the code may never even be put into the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Choice "Setup" in configuration and give the user the content of the generated folder. That's the easiest.

Other solutions take longer. Its an area of expertiese for itself.
Maybee you can build an installer with http://www.wixtoolset.org in a week.

The main other solution is InstallShield. But you have to pay for it.

Comment: OP just wants to make an exe

Comment: @KillzoneKid yes, exactly!